# Placing a <p> element inside an <hr />

Tags: html

I am trying to place a "p" element inside of a "hr" element, where the "hr" element is 33px high. Do I use a "span" or a "div" to get the "p" element nested inside the "hr" element?

This is my code:

```
<div class="pagination">
<hr class="fatLines" />
    <p>Page 1 of 2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">1</a>&nbsp;<a href="#">2</a>&nbsp;<a href="#">>></a></p>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: hr is just a line across the page. it has no content. other than the fact that it draws a line, it's like a `<br>`. You want a `<div>` with a border on it.

Comment: `"I am trying to place a "p" element inside of a "hr" element"` - No you're not, you're closing the `hr` element before the `p` element :)

Comment: I am sorry that I asked the question. I was looking for amicable advice not rudeness and sarcasm. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I think you were harshly treated. What you asked for is not [*impossible*](http://jsfiddle.net/HKgG2/2/), just nonsensical and invalid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An `HR` element is simply a line across the page. You can't put *any* content in it.

You can *float* an element *over* it, but it really makes little sense.

Might as well use a `div` with that height and style it with borders and whatever else you need.

The [HTML 5 sepecification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-hr-element) notes that the `content model` is `Empty`, meaning a `HR` element cannot contain anything.

Comment: Thanks guys! After I thought about it, I just created a <div> with the same dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

The hr element cannot have *any* element inside it. What you are asking for is impossible and does not make any sense.

> **The hr element**
>  Content model:
>  Empty.

— http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-hr-element

> `<!ELEMENT HR - O EMPTY -- horizontal rule -->`

— http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#edef-HR

Comment: Thanks guys! After I thought about it, I just created a <div> with the same dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to reach? A `<hr />` can't contain any data inside it. If you want a block you should just style it

```
<div style="background-color:#777; height: 33px;">
  My text
<div>
```

Comment: Thanks guys! After I thought about it, I just created a <div> with the same dimensions.